# Why Cygwin ssh service return (rs = 1) when running executable in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin

i have installed cygwin ssh service on windows server and configured user details and i am trying to run executables that i compiled using sshpass from Linux server and i am always getting return status = 1 .

i have made sure that my executable return 0 , but for some reason its not working .

here is the example i am trying to run

```
sshpass -p 'herod11' ssh herod@pcie191 'cmd /c \\\\10.128.0.102\\fwshared_gwork\\ibrahims\\git\\svx\\pci_verification\\win_64\\build\\\pcie_call_crspace_function --mst_dev mt4117_pciconf0 --tags  --function_name GetPciPort '
```

echo $? , return 1 .

Comment: The return code you print is the return code of the `sshpass` command. And the return code `1` means (according to [this manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass)) "Invalid command line argument". Are you sure there can be a space between the `-p` argument and the password?

Comment: yes you can run it with the space , i have tried running other commands such as whoami ,DIR and the commands returned 0 .

Comment: Are you able to run it otherwise? e.g. `sshpass  --help`? Also, are you able to run (other, simple) remote commands? That seems a complex command, try breaking it into pieces and see which one fails.

Comment: my mistake that i didnot update that i solved the issue .  it was test issue somehow it fails when running remotely and passed when running directly in cmd , i solved it